# SSRS Sql R2 Deployment in IIS or Native

Tags: deployment, webserver, ssrs-2008, native

I am in the process of designing SSRS SQL R2 reports. In previous versions we have to host it in IIS. What i would like to know from group is as part of R2 you can only deploy reports in SQL Native http web server which comes with SQL SSRS or on Sharepoint. We are not deploying in Sharepoint.

What is the best practice to deploy a enterprice wide Reporting server? 
Is SQL server Native webserver is capabile enough to handle the larger traffic and is it secure as IIS 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

Moving SSRS out from IIS and onto http.sys was intended to improve security and performance. IIS uses http.sys as well.  With the new versions SSRS avoids the install of many features that might have exploits or performance hits: "such as anonymous, client certificate and ISAPI"  ( http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=748 )

If you are concerned about performance, I'd be surprised if a SSRS install without IIS would support any smaller load than with IIS installed. Depending on your reports and network, you might miss the benefit of http compression provided by IIS, but that can be implemented in http.sys(1). Security is likely improved as well; the number of black-hats looking for exploits in SSRS or even http.sys is much smaller than those looking for problems in IIS.

(1) http://www.wickedprogrammer.com/post/2010/04/29/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-HTTP-Compression-and-Native-Mode-Installation.aspx

http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39004/1763/page/4

Comment: In addition to that if you need to scale we add the deploy the SSRS distributly by scaling out